# how to track conversion without users viewing a page?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-ads-api

I have a website where customers may submit orders and I have Adwords campaign on it.
However, they may not necessarily proceed with the payment of the order.

I'd like to track my final conversion on google analytics such that my ECommerce transactions are tracked only when the customers have paid and informed us offline.

How can I track the following conversion:
1. User clicks on Adwords ads.
2. User browse website. <-- Already tracked in analytics
3. User clicks 'Purchase'. <-- First Conversion
4. User makes payment and inform us.
5. **WE** update our website order systems with payment information. <-- WANT TO TRACK THIS

PLUS: I wish to consider number 5 as the ultimate conversion not only relating it to number 3, but also number 1! Is there any good way to do this?
Specifically I am not very familiar with the details of the tracking flow enough to manipulate the important variables to submit to google by myself. I'm worried about things like what if at step 5, the IP address that request to Google Analytics is not the same as that of the users' in step 1, will the 'source/medium' tracking be broken?

Hope someone may know of any idea or even a help page specific to my case can help.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the questions, no, there is not a good way to do this and yes, source/medium tracking will be broken albeit for a different reason than you think.

GA does not use IP adresses for tracking (in some countries using IP adresses isn't even legal). The Google code assigns a visitor id to recognzie a user (more precise, the browser - ids are stored in a cookie) and session ids to the visitor id to recognize recurring visits. Also the code stores a lot of information in the browsers cookie, among other things source and medium.

To do what you want the user would have to look at the Google analytics cookie in his javascript console, send to you at least the visitor id, session id, timestamps, source, medium etc. Then you would have to create manually a gif request that sends that data to the Google server.

To avoid misunderstandings, I'm not suggesting that you do that, I'm telling you why there is no good way to do this. It's better to use Ga for the things it was designed to do and look into CRM systems or something if you need to track conversions offline.

Comment: Thank you @eike  Yes this is exactly the answer I needed. To know that I'm going on the right track. I suspected something hacky like stealing the visitor id but could never be sure because I'm still very young in Javascript and GA world. Really appreciate your clarification of not-using-ip and visitor-id, gif request, and lastly, what GA is NOT for ;)